# Ввод/вывод списка в файле

Tags: java

Хочу сделать хранение аккаунтов в списке после чего в файле, но что-то идёт не так. Принцип такой, что я передаю объект в файл, после чего записываю список в файл, но для того чтобы не потерять аккаунт нужно считать список и считать все объекты в нем, в чем у меня и возникает проблема. Вот код:

Передаю объект с логином и паролем :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(tfLogin.getText().length()>=0 && tfPassword.getText().length()>=0 && tfPasswordTwo.getText().equals(tfPassword.getText())){
                AllGamers.saveAccaunt(new LoginAndPass(tfLogin.getText(), tfPassword.getText()));
```

Записываю его в файл:

```
public static void saveAccaunt(LoginAndPass gamers) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("teeeest.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

        test = new ArrayList<>();
        test.add(gamers);

        objectOutputStream.writeObject(test);

        objectOutputStream.flush();
        objectOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

А теперь нужно как-то считать список из файла чтобы не пропали старые аккаунты, не могу понять как это сделать.

Comment: Вы каждый раз перезаписываете файл листом с одной записью.

Answer (score 0):

В таком случае в чем проблема считать список с файла, добавить в него новый аккаунт и записать в обратно файл? Если я все правильно понял, то думаю следующий код будет правильным (возможно где-то ошибился, т.к. писал на скорую руку). Также в вашем примере не нужно было писать flush() (он вызывается в методе close()), а лучше заключить все в try-with-resources.

```
public static void saveAccaunt(LoginAndPass gamers) {
    try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("teeeest.txt");
         ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream)
    ) {
        test = (ArrayList<LoginAndPass>) objectInputStream.readObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    test.add(gamers);

    try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("teeeest.txt");
         ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream)
    ) {
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(test);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```